# Avoiding nested for loop when read files in pandas for comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary called "file_dic" with the {key:file_path} structure. I want to read in the file path in pandas dataframe, grab the columns, and see if it exists in the other file paths in the dictionary. My solution works, but i want to avoid a nested for loop. What would be the best way to do this? I'm trying to learn better code lol

```
file_diff = {}
        for i in file_dic.keys():
            temp_col1 = pd.read_csv(file_dic[i], nrows=1).columns.tolist()
            for j in file_dic.keys():
                if (j != i):
                    temp_col2 = pd.read_csv(file_dic[j], nrows=1).columns.tolist()
                    diff_cols = sorted(list(set(temp_col1).difference(set(temp_col2))))
                    file_diff[str(i)+' columns not in '+str(j)] = diff_cols
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file_diff, orient='index').T
```

Comment: Why would j==i? Python dictionaries don't support duplicated keys

Comment: because i'm looping through the same dictionary and don't want the same file path to be compared to each other

Comment: Does each key have only one file path? Can these file paths be the same for different keys?

Comment: each key has a unique file path

Comment: If each key is unique and each value of the key is also unique then j will never equal i, your second loop is unnecessary

Comment: then how can i compare the i th file to every file in the dicitonary except for itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments your second loop isn't necessary, you can use a `count` variable to check if you are on the first key (first file) and a `previous` variable to keep track of the file you read on the previous iterations:

```
file_diff = {}
count = 0
for i in file_dic.keys():
    if count == 0: ## if first file
        previous = pd.read_csv(file_dic[i], nrows=1).columns.tolist()
        previous_key = i
    else:
        temp_col2 = pd.read_csv(file_dic[j], nrows=1).columns.tolist()
        diff_cols = sorted(list(set(previous).difference(set(temp_col2))))
        file_diff[str(previous_key)+' columns not in '+str(i)] = diff_cols
        previous = temp_col2
        previous_key = i
    count += 1
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file_diff, orient='index').T
```

This way, `previous` stores the previous file read and compare it to the new file read (`temp_col2`)

Comment: where is j coming from?

Comment: It should be i, I copied your code and forgot to change that

Comment: No worries, I just edited the answer to also save the previous key since you need it.

Comment: wait your code only compared the first file to the other files, I want to iterate it to where each file is compared to all the files in the dictionary not just the first

Comment: previous is updated after every iteration so you compare the previously read file with the current file. Do you want to compare it to all other files or just the previous one?

Comment: let's say in this dictionary there are 5 keys = [a,b,c,d,e]. I ran your code and its only doing the comparison for a-b, a-c, a-d, a-e. It should be doing a-b,a-c,a-d,a-e,b-a,b-c,b-d,b-e and etc..